# Wp theme error PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, themes

Hello guys i got new WP theme and i cant install im getting this error on website

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in
>   /storage/h3/665/790665/public_html/wp-content/themes/gameaddict/post_templates.php
>   on line 1

```
<?php
class Single_Post_Template_Plugin {
    function __construct() {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_metabox' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'metabox_save' ), 1, 2 );
        add_filter( 'single_template', array( $this, 'get_post_template' ) );
    }
    function get_post_template( $template ) {
        global $post;
        $custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_post_template', true );
        if( !$custom_field )
            return $template;
        /** Prevent directory traversal */
        $custom_field = str_replace( '..', '', $custom_field );
        if( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . "/{$custom_field}" ) )
            $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/{$custom_field}";
        elseif( file_exists( get_template_directory() . "/{$custom_field}" ) )
            $template = get_template_directory() . "/{$custom_field}";
        return $template;
    }
    function get_post_templates() {
        $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_files( 'php', 1 );
        $post_templates = array();
        $base = array( trailingslashit( get_template_directory()), trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory()) );
        foreach ( (array) $templates as $file => $full_path ) {
            if( $full_path ==  get_theme_root().'/gameaddict/post_templates.php'){continue;}else{
            if ( !preg_match( '|Single Post Template:(.*)$|mi', file_get_contents( $full_path ), $header ))
                continue;
            $post_templates[ $file ] = _cleanup_header_comment( $header[1] );
        }}
        return $post_templates;
    }
    function post_templates_dropdown() {
        global $post;
        $post_templates = $this->get_post_templates();
        /** Loop through templates, make them options */
        foreach ( (array) $post_templates as $template_file => $template_name ) {
            $selected = ( $template_file == get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_post_template', true ) ) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            $opt = '<option value="' . esc_attr( $template_file ) . '"' . $selected . '>' . esc_html( $template_name ) . '</option>';
            echo $opt;
        }
    }
    function add_metabox() {

         $screens = array( 'post', 'portfolio' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'pt_post_templates',
            __( 'Sidebar position', 'addict' ),
            array( $this, 'metabox' ),
            $screen,'normal', 'high'

        );
    }


    }
    function metabox( $post ) {
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="pt_noncename" id="pt_noncename" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ?>" />
        <label class="hidden" for="post_template"><?php  _e( 'Post Template', 'addict' ); ?></label><br />
        <select name="_wp_post_template" id="post_template" class="dropdown">
            <?php $this->post_templates_dropdown(); ?>
        </select>
        <?php
    }
    function metabox_save( $post_id, $post ) {
        /*
         * Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
         * because save_post can be triggered at other times
         */
        if(isset($_POST['pt_noncename'])){
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pt_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
            return $post->ID;
         }
        /** Is the user allowed to edit the post or page? */
        if(isset($_POST['post_type'])){
        if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post->ID ) )
                return $post->ID;
        else
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ) )
                return $post->ID;
        }
        /** OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data */
        /** Put the data into an array to make it easier to loop though and save */
        if(isset($_POST['_wp_post_template'])){
        $mydata['_wp_post_template'] = $_POST['_wp_post_template'];
        }
        /** Add values of $mydata as custom fields */
        if(isset($mydata)){
        foreach ( $mydata as $key => $value ) {
            /** Don't store custom data twice */
            if( 'revision' == $post->post_type )
                return;
            /** If $value is an array, make it a CSV (unlikely) */
            $value = implode( ',', (array) $value );
            /** Update the data if it exists, or add it if it doesn't */
            if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, false ) )
                update_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
            else
                add_post_meta( $post->ID, $key, $value );
            /** Delete if blank */
            if( !$value )
                delete_post_meta( $post->ID, $key );
        }}
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'post_templates_plugin_init' );
/**
 * Instantiate the class after theme has been set up.
 */
function post_templates_plugin_init() {
    new Single_Post_Template_Plugin;
}
```

Comment: did you write the theme? if not ask the authour

Comment: You sure this is the right file? there is no `}` on line 1.

Comment: https://teamdemo.000webhostapp.com/wp-admin/themes.php?activated=true

Comment: when i uploaded all files in ftp then tryed activate on website i get this error always

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the theme is this one https://themeforest.net/item/game-addict-clan-war-gaming-theme/6771881 and it's purchased from themeforest, it should work right out of the box. Try downloading it again, make sure to check if there is not a zipped file inside of the zip you are downloading to make sure you are uploading the right file, sometimes the zip you download has a lot of files like documentation and demos, but the actual theme file is another zip inside.
If nothing of the above helps, write to their customer support.

Comment: Can you tell me what the zip you are uploading to the site contains inside? A screenshot will do

Comment: game-addict.zip this folder im uploading

Comment: did you try uploading it via ftp?

Comment: yes, and another thing even if i delete half of code on that post_template it will give me same error

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's complaining that `wp-content/themes/gameaddict/post_templates.php` has a `}` on line 1, while PHP was expecting end of a file. The code you've included seems fine. The issue is most likely about the developer closing a bracket without opening it, somewhere in the code. It seems like you're using a pre-made theme, in that case contacting the developer would be the best option.